# Should the first instance of an author-made word in a work use an accent mark?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, writing-style, stress

If an author makes up proper nouns for their text, for example, *Bilgebauth*, should the very first instance in the text be typeset with an accent: *Bilgeb**á**uth* to inform the reader of the proper stress for that word, and should the rest of its instances be typeset without an accent mark?

Comment: If you are going to use an accent, you should be consistent (use it every time).

Comment: There is no character **á** in English, so the question is inherently Off Topic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Surely the question "Should I do X when writing English?" counts as a question about English even when the answer to it happens to be "no."

Comment: There are few things more annoying and stupid than fantasy novels where everyone has names like Bárábáb and lives in places with names like Gìrìgìg.

Comment: Where did the idea that an accent mark represents stress come from?  English does not have this concept.

Comment: @Jim Yes, it does occasionally - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_terms_with_diacritical_marks

Comment: @KateBunting - Right, but do any of those indicate stress?  I don't know of any diacritics used in English (outside of dictionary pronunciation guides) where they indicate where stress should be placed.

Comment: @Jim From the section 'Native English words' - The acute and grave accents are occasionally used in poetry and lyrics: the acute to indicate stress overtly where it might be ambiguous (rébel vs. rebél) or nonstandard for metrical reasons (caléndar); the grave to indicate that an ordinarily silent or elided syllable is pronounced (warnèd, parlìament).

Comment: @KateBunting - Thanks.  I've never run across that.  Interesting.  That, then, would indicate that OP ***could*** use an *aigu* to indicate stress.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey ....after Tolkien, right?

Comment: @Mitch - he has a lot to an answer for.

Answer (score 2):

No, accent marks should not be used that way.

In Russian, an accent mark is sometimes used on an unfamiliar word to indicate the position of the stress. For example, [the Russian Wikipedia article about Barack Obama](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0,_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA) spells his name as "Бара́к Оба́ма" the first time, but "Барак Обама" all subsequent times.

However, accent marks are rarely if ever used that way in English, so I don't think that people will understand you if you use them that way.

There is simply no good way to indicate the pronunciation of a word in English; the least-worst options are to give a phonetic respelling (something like bill-geh-BOWTH), or to use a phonetic alphabet such as IPA.